# Codeigniter echo form_open() function is not working

Tags: php

`echo form_open();` is not working in CodeIgniter.
This is the code which I have written in view page.

```
<?php include ('public_header.php');?>
<div class="container">

 <?php echo form_open('login/user_login'); ?>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Admin Login</legend>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="inputEmail" class="col-lg-2 control-label">User Name</label>
```

And this is the code which I have written in my login controller

```
<?php
class Login extends MY_Controller{
    public function index()
    {
    $this->load->helper('form');
    $this->load->view('public/admin_login');
    }

   public function user_login()
   {
     echo "user login function";
   }
}
```

But it gives not found error.

> "HTTP Error 404. The requested resource is not found."

What could be the problem?

Comment: Maybe `login/user_login` path doesn't exist. Make sure you have `user_login` function inside `login` controller.

Comment: I have defined that function already and my controller class function is also attached but it's not working.

Comment: Try passing the absolute URL like `/login/user_login`. This URL goes from the host root directory.